# Getting feature class from File Geodatabase in ArcObjects using VB.NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, file-geodatabase, vb.net, feature-class

How do you open up a File GDB and read out a simple feature class?

The snippet for retreiving a shapefile from a regular folder on disk works, and I suppose I can use the same code but with a different kind of workspace.

```
''' <summary>
''' Get the FeatureClass from a Shapefile on disk (hard drive).
''' </summary>
''' <param name="string_ShapefileDirectory">A System.String that is the directory where the shapefile is located. Example: "C:\data\USA"</param>
''' <param name="string_ShapefileName">A System.String that is the shapefile name. Note: the shapefile extension's (.shp, .shx, .dbf, etc.) is not provided! Example: "States"</param>
''' <returns>An IFeatureClass interface. Nothing (VB.NET) or null (C#) is returned if unsuccessful.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function GetFeatureClassFromShapefileOnDisk(ByVal string_ShapefileDirectory As System.String, ByVal string_ShapefileName As System.String) As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass

  Dim directoryInfo_check As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(string_ShapefileDirectory)
  If directoryInfo_check.Exists Then

    'We have a valid directory, proceed

    Dim fileInfo_check As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(string_ShapefileDirectory + "\" + string_ShapefileName + ".shp")
    If fileInfo_check.Exists Then

      'We have a valid shapefile, proceed

      Dim workspaceFactory As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass
      Dim workspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(string_ShapefileDirectory, 0)
      Dim featureWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace = CType(workspace, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace) ' Explict Cast
      Dim featureClass As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(string_ShapefileName)

      Return featureClass
    Else

      'Not valid shapefile
      Return Nothing
    End If

  Else

    ' Not valid directory
    Return Nothing

  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your project is setup correctly, with all references added and compiles without errors.  Using Visual Studio Express 2013, ArcGIS 10.3 and targeting .Net framework 3.5

Also ensure you add ArcObjects Library References to:

- DataSourcesGDB
- GeoDatabase
- Carto

```vb
Public Sub New()
On Error GoTo Trap

    Dim sPathFGDB As String
    Dim sFCName As String
    Dim pFC As IFeatureClass
    Dim pWorkSpace As IFeatureWorkspace
    Dim pWorkspaceFactory As IWorkspaceFactory = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory

    sPathFGDB = InputBox("Enter path to FGDB:", "Path to FGDB", "C:\Users\jakub.sisak\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb") 'enter a valid path including the ".gdb" extension
    pWorkSpace = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(sPathFGDB, 0)    
    sFCName = InputBox("Enter Feature Class Name:", "Feature Class Name", "Closure_Plan_GA_Footprint_DE") 'enter a valid feature class name
    pFC = pWorkSpace.OpenFeatureClass(sFCName)

    Dim pLayer As IFeatureLayer
    pLayer = New FeatureLayer
    pLayer.FeatureClass = pFC
    pLayer.Name = pFC.AliasName

    Dim pMxDoc As ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument = My.ArcMap.Document    
    pMxDoc.FocusMap.AddLayer(pLayer)
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeography, pLayer, Nothing)

Exit Sub
Trap:
    MsgBox(Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of preference for code that is closer to C# and more .NET friendly, I would replace replace the `On Error GoToTrap` and `Trap` with a `Try Catch Finally` block.  Also, I would replace the `MsgBox` with the `Forms` `MessageBox` and `InputBox` with a custom form (since there isn't a C# `InputBox` equivalent.  It'll all work, but I have seen more examples using more .NET libraries as opposed to the VB6 (VisualBasic.dll) libraries.  I just find it easier when writing code in both VB.NET and C# to translate when I exclude VB6 items.

Comment: Thanks for your input. OP is asking about VB.Net not C#.  This procedure illustrates the mechanics of getting then adding a FGDB Feature to Map which is the focus here.

Comment: Yes which is why I posted as a comment. It is better to adapt to C# style VB.NET instead of VB6 since VB6 is a legacy style.

Comment: @Jakub thank you very much! That was quite easy! I was too fixated on the fileInfo existance check, but a path to a feature class in a gdb is kind of hard to manage. I used IWorkspace2.NameExist() instead. Thanks for also adding how to add the layer to a map!

Comment: @Branco I agree, I don't know a lot of VB6, I'm a C# guy who's working on a vb project for a change so I also stick to the .NET framework

Comment: @BramVanHelleputte - NP. If it answered your question, please check as answered. Thanks. Yes, IWorkspace2 supersedes IWorkspace so it should be used instead especially if it provides additional functionality such as what you describe.

Comment: Not in this case Bram, IWorkspace2 only has NameExists and no other methods, so you can't replace IWorkspace with IWorkspace2 (not like ITopologicalOperator2 etc).. you cast from IWorkspace and test if the name string you've got exists in the database (workspace) *before* trying to open it. IWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile returns IWorkspace which can be cast to both of IWorkspace2 and IFeatureWorkspace. Nice explanantion/code Jakub +1 from me.

Comment: I forgot to add that IWorkspace2 is only implemented on geodatabase (personal, file and SDE) and does not work for shapefiles.. use FileInfo object to see if each of the components exist (not guaranteed to be valid) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.exists(v=vs.110).aspx.