# Adding *.gdb to ArcGIS user interface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase

```vb
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\Workspace\Data.gdb"
rst.Open "SELECT DISTINCT [Adi],[KimlikNo]FROM MahalleSiniri ORDER BY [Adi];", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
rst.MoveFirst
    ComboBox4.Clear
    With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
   ComboBox1.Text = "Mahalle Seçiniz..."
    Do
        ComboBox1.AddItem rst![Adi]
        ComboBox4.AddItem rst![KimlikNo]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
'UserForm_Initialize_Exit:'
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
End Sub
```

In this code block, I can add *.mdb database to my interface and it works fine. But my data contains raster data and I want it to connect to a *.gdb database file.

How can I correct it? I tried several solutions I found on the internet but they didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gdb is a proprietary Esri file geodatabase and you will not be able to connect to it using the method you are using (JET engine is for Access).

You need to reference ArcObjects libraries and use ArcObjects to access datasets in these types of geodatabases.

Have a look at [Getting feature class from File Geodatabase in ArcObjects using VB.NET?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148117) to get an idea of what you need to be doing.